# Empty contact form after JS validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, email

We are receiving empty emails from our site contact form, and we don't know why. 
Our form is very simple and the validation is also not so advanced, but enough for our purpose.

We have 5 fields:

- Name (text input)
- mail (text input)
- phone (text input)
- reason (select, 3 values)
- message (textarea)

Then with JS we validate all fields. Finally, with submit, we send the mail with php mail function:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail= $_POST['mail'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$reason= $_POST['reason'];
$message= $_POST['message'];

$header = 'From: ' . $mail. " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$msg.= "Name: " . $name . " \r\n";
$msg.= "Mail: " . $mail. " \r\n";
$msg.= "Phone: " . $phone. " \r\n";
$msg.= "Reason: " . $reason. " \r\n";
$msg.= "Message: " . $message. " \r\n";

$for= "ourmail@ourserver.com";
$as= "Contact form";

mail($for, $as, $msg, $header);
?>
```

In general, works OK. But sometimes we receive an email with ALL (including reason... which is a select!) fields empty. Something like:

```
Subject: Contact form
Name:
Mail:
Phone:
Reason:
Message:
```

How can this be?

Comment: A code or some pieces should be great

Comment: the reason we need code you might be sending empty string in js overwritten variables

Comment: I don't have the code right now but I will have it soon. But, it only fails sometimes....

Comment: Select can be empty if user does not check any item.

Comment: Also with selected="selected" ¿? I didn't know that.

Comment: @gladnick Please don't pepper questions with code formatting where it isn't appropriate. Code formatting is for, well, code - not for general emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumming you are sending the data through POST:

Have you considered that the action url may be directly accesed from the browser without any kind of POST data?. That would make all the "fields" empty.

If that's the case You can try a server validation in several ways:

- Add a referer validation so that the url may only be accesed from the form url. Your can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for that purpose but keep in mind that may not always be available.
- Find out if the data is sent. You can use isset for that purpose like in `if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])` in order to add a server validation. You can always do this `$name=isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'no_name_entered'` and have the email sent anyway.
- Add a hidden input like "contacting" within your form and check if it's set server side: `if(!isset($_POST['contacting'])) die('ERROR: Form not sent');`

Anyway, keep in mind that most data you recieve can be tainted, even the ones sent through a select field.

Comment: Thanks! I also added an header location to the contact form if someone goes directly to that action url.

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad that helped. I suggest you take into consideration what Sumesh told you in the other solution since it could be also happening. Everything ends up adding to his reply: server side validation.

Comment: I'll do it too. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

Create server side validation using php script.

**Demostration**

```
if($_POST['Name']=="") {
    $err = "Enter the name";
}
if($_POST['mail']=="") {
    .......
}

......
if($err=="") {
    //mail function
}
else {
    echo $err;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'll try that, but I really want to know what happens now. What happens?

Comment: Mail has been sending from JS disabled browsers.

Comment: I disabled JS in Firefox for trying that, and I cannot even send the form... because submit calls a Javascript function.

Comment: I think that your php file has been running by some spammer. It is safe to include if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { .... } in the mail running code.

Comment: Can I use that if: <input name="Submit" type="button" class="but" onclick="validaform();" onkeypress="validaform();" value="send" /> AND in my ACTION JS: document.forms["myform"].submit(); any suggestion?